# Laravel Undefined offset: 2 in for loop

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I want to add table grid dynamically with one color and multiple image but in controller for loop i get undefined offset:2 error

here is my grid html code:

```html
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Image</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="imgcolor[]" />
        <div class="field col-sm-10" align="left">
          <input type="file" class="files" name="image[0][]" multiple />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Image</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="imgcolor[]" />
        <div class="field col-sm-10" align="left">
          <input type="file" class="files" name="image[1][]" multiple />
        </div>
    </div>
```

in my controller code:

```php
     $input = $request->all();
        $color = $request->input('imgcolor');
        for($i=0; $i <= count($input['imgcolor']); $i++) {
            for($j=0; $j <= count($request->image[$i]); $j++) {  // here Undefined offset: 2
                $data = $request->file('image')[$i][$j];
                $imagename = $data->getClientOriginalName();
                $data->move('uploads/product/', $imagename);
                Image::create([
                    'product_id' => $product->id,
                    'color_id' => $color[$i],
                    'image' => $imagename
                ]);
            }
        }
```

actually i need to store data in image table like one color multiple images.

Comment: What does the form actually submit? It looks like `imgcolor[]` and `image[]` aren't the same length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `$i = count($input['imgcolor']);` with `$i < count($input['imgcolor']);`.

**Same** for inner loop with `$j` counter.

Comment: i already tried that. updated my questions thanks

Comment: Strictly `<`, not `<=`.

Comment: Do you understand __why__ it works?

Comment: explain please??

Comment: Because indexes in array are started from `0`. If you have __3__ elements in array their indexes are `0`, `1`, `2`.